# Cannot reference raw resources from Network Security Configuration XML

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-xml, android-network-security-config

I'm trying to follow the Android documentation for using custom certs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas). The desired network config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/extracas"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I have already created network_security_config.xml and have added the reference a`ndroid:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to my manifes. I have .crt files I need to include but I am having two problems:

1. I cannot create a directory in my raw folder, when I do, it creates the directory in my file system but not in my raw resource directory in the project.
2. In lieu of a directory I just reference my .crt files directly in the raw folder, but when I try to reference the certs, here's my network_security_config.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <base-config>
           <trust-anchors>
               <certificates src="@raw/cert_cubic_trusted_ca-sha256.crt"/>
               <certificates src="system"/>
           </trust-anchors>
       </base-config>
   </network-security-config>
   ```

I get a red squiggle with error "missing src resource.", and when I attempt to build, the build log outputs error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource raw/certname.crt (aka com.comname.appname:raw/certname.crt) not found.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/205314/project/appname/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml","position":{"startLine":5}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:processDebugResources
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
```

I do not know why I am unable to reference assets in my raw resource folder from XML or create a folder within it, this seems to be my biggest issue. I can reference raw resources with R.raw in code but I have never needed to reference using @raw and I'm not sure why it isn't working as described.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per the [Accessing resources documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing), the resource name is

> the filename, **excluding the extension**

So you need to remove the `.crt` from your `src`:

```
<certificates src="@raw/cert_cubic_trusted_ca-sha256"/>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness yes you're right. And I already checked that doc link and totally missed it haha. Geez I might be asking the same question in a year for all I know. Thank you very much!